# Ubuntu install stops at "Creating ext4 file system for / in partition #1 of SCSI2 (0,0,0) (sdb)..."

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation, windows-8

I'm installing desktop ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS 64 bit on my second HDD (160GB). I have my main 1TB WD HDD for windows 8.1. When installing ubuntu on the newly formatted hard drive it always stops at "Creating ext4 file system for / in partition #1 of SCSI2 (0,0,0) (sdb)...".
I'm booting it from a 8GB Kingston pendrive. I ran a memory and drive test, didn't find any errors. I tried multiple times, but nothing worked. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Physically disconnect main 1TB hard drive data cable from motherboard, connect your NEW (2nd) hard drive to system using a different data port on motherboard, and leave main disconnected, boot system from pendrive and install UBUNTU onto (2nd) hard drive, after installing UBUNTU to 2nd hard drive, REconnect main hard drive to it's original data port. If you do not already have it, I would recommend downloading Boot-Repair-Disk from sourceforge.net onto a dvd and booting to repair disk first thing and let repair disk set-up GRUB, after Boot-Repair-Disk has done it's magic, REBOOT system and you will have a choice of the two hard drive you have installed. I have 3 hard drives on my GATEWAY PC and this procedure has worked flawlessly every time. I have Ubuntu 14.04 & windows 7 on one drive, ubuntu 15.04 on drive #2, and RoboLinux on drive #3, the KEY here is to let Boot-Repair-Disk do it's magic to GRUB and everything should be PEACHY :-)

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem, so I solved that by formatting partitions in GParted before installing. Hope it will helpful for anybody!